# Displaying Data in GridView using Dataset

Tags: data-binding, ado.net, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to display a dataset to my ASP.NET application. It seems that when I click the button event, the data is not displaying in the grid.

I have a basic page with the following:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="200" Height="300">
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:Button runat="server" id="UpdateButton1" onclick="UpdateButton_Click" text="Update" />               
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </form>
```

Then in the code behind, I have the following:

```
protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string SQLConfigSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(SQLConfigSettings);

            sqlconn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Student", sqlconn);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            UpdatePanel.Update();

        }
```

Am I missing something? Shoudlnt the dataset be diaplayed in the grid? 
When I click the button nothing happens.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

`GridView1.DataBind()` right after `Gridview1.DataSource`.

So it becomes:

```
...
          DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            UpdatePanel.Update();
```

If you need more information about the .DataBind method check [MSDN on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

Try to mention table inside dataset. Something like ds.Tables[0] or if you know name of table ds.Tables["table_name"]

Comment: @shakhar, the default takes the first table so that is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint on the first line of code in `UpdateButton_Click` and run it.

Is that breakpoint reached?

Step through each line of code after that and examine the variable values. Is the `DataSet` being filled? Can you see the `DataTable` and its `DataRows`?

If you reach this event code and have data, then you need to look at the databinding. You need to do `GridView.DataBind()` immediately after setting the `DataSource` and before doing the `UpdatePanel.Update()`. Then you should be good to go.